# How to update time part in datetime variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of type datetime. The time part of the datetime is 00:00:00.000 for all the records. How can I update all of the records so the time is set to 17:59:59.000 without altering the part that contains the date?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using DATEADD for hour, minutes, seconds, miliseconds, but it doesn't work as expected :/

Comment: `UPDATE t SET c += '17:59:59'` should actually just work. This relies on some highly dubious features of T-SQL (the fact that `DATETIME`s allow addition and implicit conversions) and will not work for `DATETIME2` or `DATETIMEOFFSET`, but hey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply `DATEADD` three times.

```
DECLARE @myDate DateTime = '2019-01-09'
SELECT @myDate
SELECT @myDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 59, DATEADD(MINUTE, 59, DATEADD(HOUR, 17, @myDate)))
SELECT @myDate
```

This produces

> 2019-01-09 00:00:00.000
>
> 2019-01-09 17:59:59.000

Answer (score 2):

do update where you got the time 00:00:00.000

```
create table t ( d datetime);
insert into t values('2019-10-01 00:00:00.000')
insert into t values('2019-10-01 00:00:00.000')

update 
t1
set d= d+ cast('17:59:59.000' as datetime)
from t t1
where cast( d as time)='00:00:00.000'
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb69c7d5655701169e9e06cacbe12866)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table(datetimefield, ....) VALUES ('2019-10-03 00:00:00', ...);
UPDATE table SET datetimefield = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datetimefield), MONTH(datetimefield), DAY(datetimefield), 17, 59, 59, 0)
```

Comment: My preferred solution, because this uses a SQL Server function specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEADD()`

```
UPDATE 
    YourTable 
SET 
    datecolumn = DATEADD(SECOND, 59, DATEADD(HOUR,17,DATEADD(MINUTE,59,datecolumn)))
WHERE 
    ID=10000
```

replace `ID`, `YourTable` and `DateColumn` with your table/column names